# Java - Get file from jar

Tags: java, file, jar, ide

I need to catch some directory within the application. For that I have a small demonstration:

```
String pkgName = TestClass.class.getPackage().getName();
String relPath = pkgName.replace(".", "/");
URL resource = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource(relPath);

File file = new File(resource.getPath());
System.out.println("Dir exists:" + file.exists());
```

While running application from IDE I receive my goal and I can find my directory. But running application as JAR file, does not return a valid "file" (from Javas perspective) and my sout gives me back `File exists:false`. Is there some way to get this file? In this case, the file is a directory.

Comment: Can you please check output of System.out.println( new File(".").getAbsolutePath()); in bothe the cases. And add it in the comment.

Comment: `System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsolutePath());` always returns the absolute path to project folder, e.g. on Windows 'C:\Users\name\path\to\project\folder\.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java ClassPath is an abstraction that differs from a filesystem abstraction.
A classpath element may exist in two physical ways:

1. exploded with classpath pointing to the root directory
2. packed in a JAR archive

Unfortunatelly, the **file.getPath** does return a File object if classpath is pointing to file system but it does not if you refer to a JAR file.

In 99% of all cases you should read the contents of a resource using **InputStream**.

Here is a snippet, that uses **IOUtils** from apache commons-io to load the whole file content into a **String**.

```
public static String readResource(final String classpathResource) {
    try {
        final InputStream is = TestClass.class.getResourceAsStream(classpathResource);
        // TODO verify is != null
        final String content = IOUtils.toString(
            is, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        return content;
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm suspecting that this just work if file is a real file, e.g. file.txt. But not for directories. Am I right? Either way I don't want to use an external library. - But a big thanks for your answer.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the "directories"? ClassPaths do not have a notion of "directories", so you cannot for example list all files in a directory. You can only have resources identified by a resourceString like "com/foo/file.txt". If you do not want to use IOUtils, you can access InputStream by its interface directly (read here http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-io/commons-io/1.4/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.java#IOUtils.copy%28java.io.InputStream%2Cjava.io.Writer%2Cjava.lang.String%29).

Comment: Thank u much! `InputStream` is a really good choice to handle resources in application, that should even run as JAR-file.